# How to get select rows that have first occurrences before column value changes in MYSQL8

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands, mysql-8.0

I have a MYSQL8 table with `Event_TimeStamp` and `FinalStateand` it looks like this

```
+---------------------------+---------------+
|"Event_TimeStamp"          |"FinalState"   |
+---------------------------+---------------+
|"2020-03-09 04:57:45.729"  |"Available"    |
|"2020-03-09 05:14:59.659"  |"Available"    |
|"2020-03-09 05:27:56.341"  |"Available"    |
|"2020-03-09 05:41:01.554"  |"Available"    |
|"2020-03-09 05:58:07.803"  |"Available"    |
|"2020-03-09 06:06:09.745"  |"Available"    |
|"2020-03-09 06:18:07.663"  |"Available"    |
|"2020-03-09 06:26:24.273"  |"Available"    |
|"2020-03-09 09:29:53.165"  |"Offline"      |
|"2020-03-09 10:28:00.514"  |"Available"    |
|"2020-03-09 12:47:54.130"  |"Available"    |
|"2020-03-09 13:01:30.117"  |"Available"    |
|"2020-03-09 13:01:59.774"  |"Offline"      |
|"2020-03-09 13:19:15.772"  |"Available"    |
|"2020-03-09 14:19:51.521"  |"Available"    |
|"2020-03-09 14:50:16.872"  |"Offline"      |
+---------------------------+---------------+
```

I have to extract rows from the above such that it will have the rows with first "Available" and "Offline", so the output would look like this

```
+---------------------------+---------------+
|"Event_TimeStamp"          |"FinalState"   |
+---------------------------+---------------+
|"2020-03-09 04:57:45.729"  |"Available"    |
|"2020-03-09 09:29:53.165"  |"Offline"      |
|"2020-03-09 10:28:00.514"  |"Available"    |
|"2020-03-09 13:01:59.774"  |"Offline"      |
|"2020-03-09 13:19:15.772"  |"Available"    |
|"2020-03-09 14:50:16.872"  |"Offline"      |
+---------------------------+---------------+
```

I tried a few ways with GROUP BY but I get only the first entries for each of the FinalState and not the rest of them.

Is there a way to get this done with an QUERY or should I write it out in PHP?

Comment: You could CSS it using the [`nth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) method.

Comment: `SELECT thetable.*, @t, @t:=FinalState from thetable join (select @t := '') t1 having @t <> FinalState`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and `lead()` to exhibit records whose `final_state` is different that in the previous or next row:

```
select
    event_timestamp,
    final_state
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        lag(final_state) over(order by event_timestamp)  lag_final_state,
        lead(final_state) over(order by event_timestamp) lead_final_state
    from mytable t
) t
where final_state <> lag_final_state or final_state <> lead_final_state
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly. I am posting answer based on your query. Thx @GMB

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using joins. I used `events` as database name example.

```sql
SELECT x.* 
  FROM events x
  JOIN
     (
       SELECT MIN(c.id) id 
         FROM events a
         LEFT 
         JOIN events b 
           ON b.FinalState = a.FinalState 
          AND b.id = a.id - 1 
         LEFT 
         JOIN events c 
           ON c.FinalState = a.FinalState
          AND c.id >= a.id
         LEFT
         JOIN events d
           ON d.FinalState = a.FinalState
          AND d.id = c.id + 1
        WHERE b.id IS NULL 
          AND c.id IS NOT NULL
          AND d.id IS NULL
        GROUP 
           BY a.id
     ) y
    ON y.id = x.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the lag function to check if the state changes:

```
with cte as
(select CAST('2020-03-09 04:57:45.729' as datetime) as Event_timestamp,'Available' as Finalstate union
select '2020-03-09 05:14:59.659','Available' union
select '2020-03-09 09:29:53.165','Offline' union
select '2020-03-09 10:28:00.514','Available')

select x.Event_timestamp,x.Finalstate
from
(select *,lag(Finalstate) Over(Order by Event_timestamp) as lag_status
from cte ) x
where x.Finalstate<>coalesce(lag_status,'Z')
```

Here is a db-fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cb59ec79e7be1363961971cea4308dff

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This query solved my problem. All thanks to @[GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716/gmb)

```
SELECT
    Event_TimeStamp,
    FinalState
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        COALESCE(LAG(FinalState) over(ORDER BY Event_TimeStamp), 'offline')  lag_final_state,
        COALESCE(lead(FinalState) over(ORDER BY Event_TimeStamp), 'offline') lead_final_state
    FROM (
        SELECT
            Event_TimeStamp, 
            FinalState
        FROM AgentTraceData
        WHERE Event_TimeStamp BETWEEN '2019-11-17' AND '2020-03-10 23:59:59.999' AND username = 'xxxx' ORDER BY Event_TimeStamp
        ) t
    ) t
WHERE FinalState <> lag_final_state
```

Which gives the following result

```
+---------------------------+-------------+
|"Event_TimeStamp"          | "FinalState"|
+---------------------------+-------------| 
|"2019-11-18 02:01:16.395"  |"online"     |
|"2019-11-18 04:34:59.739"  |"offline"    |
|"2019-11-18 04:45:08.354"  |"online"     |
|"2019-11-18 07:30:13.909"  |"offline"    |
|"2019-11-18 08:00:20.647"  |"online"     |
|"2019-11-18 10:30:08.698"  |"offline"    |
+---------------------------+-------------+
```

I am going to try to explain as much as I can.

First we need to run the query with `SELECT *` to see all the columns appearing.

The output would look like this

```
+---------------------------+---------------+-------------------+------------------+
|"Event_TimeStamp"          |"FinalState"   |"lag_final_state"  |"lead_final_state"|
+---------------------------+---------------+-------------------+------------------+
|"2019-11-18 02:01:16.395"  |"online"       |"offline"          |"online"          |
|"2019-11-18 04:34:59.739"  |"offline"      |"online"           |"online"          |
|"2019-11-18 04:45:08.354"  |"online"       |"offline"          |"online"          |
+---------------------------+---------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

As per my requirement, I wanted to know the next `FinalState` value so `final_state <> lead_final_state` was not needed.

I added `COALESCE()` cause `LEAD()` and `LAG()` will give `NULL` values for rows which do not exists above or beyond the first SELECT query.